# Cannot install Adobe Reader on 12.10 Unity

Tags: unity, 12.10, adobe

I'm unable to install Adobe Reader on my Ubuntu 12.10 Unity. I followed the directions here from [www.noobslab.com](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-adobe-acrobat-reader-in-ubuntu.html)

The first two commands did not throw any errors, but the last one went like this:

```
zach@zach-Lemur-Ultra:~$ sudo apt-get install acroread

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: acroread : Depends: ia32-libs (>= 20080808) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: lib32z1 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: nspluginwrapper but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: acroread-common but it is not going to be installed
           Conflicts: adobereader-enu:i386 adobereader-enu:i386 : Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be >installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a >solution).
```

If I try to install the dependencies by following the directions and running commands like

```
sudo apt-get -f install ia32-libs
```

I just get more list of other dependencies that need to be installed, with no end.

Is there an easy way?.

Comment: The end of what you posted said to try just `sudo apt-get -f install`. Did you try that?

Comment: I was trying so many different things, and I did not keep track.  Eventually I gave up, and then somehow I noticed that the the program actually was installed, and it seems to work. I just wish I understood all those dependency messages.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first package depends on the second which depends on the third, etc. But when you get to the (6,7,) 8th one (acroread-common), it is not going to be installed because it conflicts with adobereader-enu:i386. Just `sudo apt-get -f install` forces the install and ignores the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the Medibuntu repositories are enabled. Most third party addons are disabled after upgrading from one Ubuntu release to another.